# How to format an existing .docx file in PHPword?

Tags: php, codeigniter, docx, phpword

I'm using **PHPword** *library* to formant an existing `.docx` file, But I could only replace a particular item from the original document. I actually want to change the *styling* of the whole document. Can anyone tell how to achieve this.

My Code:

```
 <?php

    require_once 'phpWord/PHPWord.php';

    $PHPWord = new PHPWord();

    $document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('test.docx');

    $test = 'Indian';

    // Replacing The word 'British' with 'Indian'
    $document->setValue('British', $test); 

    $document->save('test2.docx');

 ?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Load existing file as template.
2. Make the desired editing
3. Save file.

Check example [here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/samples/Sample_07_TemplateCloneRow.php)

Answer (score 0):

You'll find in this [link](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/src/PhpWord/PhpWord.php) the methods of the PHPWord class.

Perform a CTRL + F searching for "style" and you'll find all the related methods.

edit: You'll also be able to see the internal behaviour of the functions ;)

Comment: Could you try this dirty trick ?:
- Retrieve the existing file's content you need
- Delete the existing file
- Create a new one combining the style you wanted with the content you retrieved

Comment: Good thinking, But a .docx file doesn't contain only Texts.

Comment: Can you delete the actual file while keeping an instance of it in your program, apply the style to the instance, and then recreate it using the instance ?